# Zend reset button unable to clear fields

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, reset

When I want to display a form for editing some row of a table, I fill the values into its field. But then when I click the reset button, it doesn't clear the form fields. Please help. Thanks

Comment: @Syed Moazam Ali Shal please provide your code that you are using

Comment: Problem is almost solved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reset button doesn't "clear" all the fields.

A reset button "RESETS" the form to the way it was upon initialization. A "addForm" usually has no fields filled out, so reset button makes all fields go empty again. Because they were empty when the form was displayed first. A "editForm" usually has data filled out. All those data are saved now by the browser, when you change the data and hit reset, it grabs all saved data and brings them back into the form - thus resetting it.